# Timeout setting will cause undefined method error

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to set the the global timeout in my project.

For example, when I click a button and head for an new page.

I want to give it a timeout in `5 seconds`.

However when the exception occurs it only give me the `NoMethodError: undefined method`

```
# @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
# @driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 5
```

Comment: which client library you are using with selenium?

Comment: ruby binding library

Comment: would you kindly provide more code and illustrate where exactly the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are attempting to call the method on a `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` object? Before you make the method call, try doing a `puts @driver.class` and seeing what's output. You should see `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver` returned.

For simplicity, try making the calls when you first instantiate your driver object. For example:

```
@browser ||= Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
@browser.manage.timeouts.page_load = 5
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.